# Eliom error: {client{}}

Tags: client, ocaml, ocsigen

I am running into an error that I do not know how to resolve. I have the following code (from the Eliom Graffiti tutorial) which I am trying to test with `make test.byte`.

```
open Eliom_content.Html5.D

module My_app =
Eliom_registration.App (struct
  let application_name = "graffiti"
end)

let main_service =
  Eliom_registration.Html5.register_service
    ~path:[""]
    ~get_params:Eliom_parameter.unit
    (fun () () ->
      Lwt.return
        (html
          (head (title (pcdata "Graffiti")) [])
          (body [h1 [pcdata "Graffiti"]])))

{client{
  let _ = Eliom_lib.alert "Hello!"
}}
```

Error:

```
$ make test.byte
eliomc -c   graffiti.ml 
File "graffiti.ml", line 18, characters 0-1:
Parse error: [label_expr_list] or [expr level .] expected after "{" (in [expr])
Error while running external preprocessor
```

line 18 is where `{client{` appears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `graffiti.ml` should be named `graffiti.eliom`, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

`~path[""]` seems to be missing a `:` at least

(I caught this by just pasting your code into Emacs; the syntax highlighting showed it.)

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the code in my question. My actual code did have the ':' character.